# How to execute programs of different languages in android app

Tags: android, flutter, android-library, android-native-library

I'm building an app where students can learn different programming languages like java, c++, JavaScript, markup languages like html, xml etc.

I want to create a simple editor inside my app to run programs to show output of those programs.

I'll be grateful to you if you will suggest any Libraries or resources that I will need to run these programs inside my android app.

My main technology will be flutter. But Using platform channels in flutter you execute android native code too. So any combination of flutter libraries and android native libraries, or just one of these to run these programs will be fine.

Some apps I'm attaching for examples

1. [Acode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxdebug.acodefree)
2. [Code editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.code)